# Changing Theme code of Wordpress via Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

How can I changing/ adding code of the Themes with a wordpress plugin? Example: Adding before or after the comments-forms a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need action hooks in your themes. These hooks allow you to add content where the hooks are locating via a plugin, or a [child theme](http://op111.net/53).

Thesis and Thematic are WordPress themes with action hooks. Although it's easy to add action hooks to your own theme.

In the theme, add `do_action('your_hook_name')`. For example, in the `comments.php` file:

```
do_action('after_comments_form');
```

Now, in your plugin/child theme, add, for example,

```
add_action('after_comments_form', 'commenting_rules');
```

. This means we're adding the `commenting_rules()` function to the hook `after_comments_form`.

The `commenting_rules()` function could look like:

```
function commenting_rules(){
    echo "No spam or similar, read our <a href=\"" . bloginfo('url') . "\"/commenting-rules\">Commenting Rules</a>";
}
```

Be sure you add the `add_action()` function below the `commenting_rules()` function.

Themeshaper (the creator of the Thematic) has a [great article on that](http://themeshaper.com/action-hooks-wordpress-child-themes/). Nathan Rice has also written a post [explaining action hooks](http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/an-introduction-to-wordpress-action-hooks/).

Comment: I found the solution, so I've forgot to look here :)
My Plugin was approved :D
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slide2comment/